# ReferenceError from a JavaScript function that is defined correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I've declared myself a JavaScript object called "breakdown".

I've then borrowed a function which I found on the jQuery extend() documentation, which works perfectly well on a different page, but identical setup - rewards object instead of breakdown.

```
breakdown = {};

breakdown.printObj = function(obj) { 
    var arr = []; 
    $.each(obj, function(key, val) { 
        var next = key + ": "; 
        next += $.isPlainObject(val) ? printObj(val) : val; 
        arr.push( next ); 
    }); 
    return "{ " +  arr.join(", ") + " }"; 
}
```

I'm then trying to use it as I have on the other page to see what is in my "categories" array:

```
breakdown.getPointsBreakdown = function(categories, transactions) {

    alert( breakdown.printObj(categories) );
```

If I "typeof" that alert instead, it displays "object". If I alert "categories[1].Title", it displays "Good Behaviour", so the array is being passed to the categories variable in this function correctly.

However, when I use "breakdown.printObj", I get the following error in FireBug:

```
ReferenceError { message="printObj is not defined", fileName="https://frog.ashingtonh...7fa8452ccb3e94ba89e487a", more...}
```

I don't understand how!

Comment: Where are you alerting 'breakdown.printObj'? Inside of your .each? just below your method sig?  Also, are you "varring" breakdown and you've just declared it as "breakdown = {};" for the sake of your example?  eg., is it declared in your actual code as "var breakdown = {};"?

Comment: BTW, why don't you just use a JSON serializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
    next += $.isPlainObject(val) ? printObj(val) : val;
```

to:

```
    next += $.isPlainObject(val) ? breakdown.printObj(val) : val;
```

Comment: Thanks, works a treat. Still don't understand how in my other script it works however (direct c&p)! :)

Comment: The other script must've had a `printObj` function defined somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
breakdown.printObj = function(obj) { 
    // snip...
};
```

to

```
breakdown.printObj = function printObj(obj) { 
    // snip...
};
```

so that you can call it recursively.

This is called [named function expression](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/).

Answer (score 1):

You should probably have `breakdown.printObj(val)` rather than just `printObj(val)` in line 6.